# How do I stream data to a WebView/WebFrame?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webkit

I'm writing a Cocoa application, and I want to display some data in a Webkit view.  The data is HTML that I'm generating internally.  It's coming from a slow computation, though, so I'm going to be building up a buffer (in a GCD queue, right now).

[WebFrame](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebFrame_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebFrame/loadRequest%3a) has `-loadRequest` (URL), which is asynchronous, and a bunch of methods like `-loadHTMLString` (string) and `-loadData` (raw bytes), which are synchronous.  Is there any way to load a local stream of HTML asynchronously?  Do I need to set up my own web server just to send a stream of data to this view?

Comment: Here's a thought: Load the webview with some basic HTML that contains the javascript to basically maintain an array of the HTML that has been computed. In the javascript, poll every x seconds and if there is new HTML data, display it. In the Obj C, whenever there is new data, use UIWebView's `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to append the new data to the array.

Comment: That's an interesting idea!  It's not ideal but it certainly sounds plausible.

Comment: iOS's webview is not very good at these kinds of more complicated things.

Comment: (Reread the question: I'm not using iOS.)

Comment: Do I even need a JS timer in the initial HTML?  If I'm evaluating JS in the context of that frame, can't I just add to the document content directly?

Comment: Whoops. Sorry about that. The idea should still apply though, although the OSX webview has some features that might make for a more elegant solution. And yes, I think your JS can display the data directly.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass [NSURLProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

With a custom protocol handler, you can point the WebFrame at a custom NSURL (like "myproto://foo/bar"), and then write a handler which deals with "myproto" URLs and sends whatever byte stream it likes.